# Windows CWnd::OnLButtonDown not called as expected on double click

Tags: model-view-controller, winapi, mfc

I'm developing an interactive MFC application which displays a 3D object using my own algorithm, essentially using MFC as a framework, but using lots of `pDC->Polygon(), pDC->Rectangle(), pDC->DrawText()`, etc. calls.

The UI has numerous clickable areas which all work well.  However, the onscreen controls for rotating, spinning, etc. the 3D image motivate users to double click, triple click, and beyond.

I'm 99% positive that `CWnd::OnLButtonDown()` is not called until Windows (or whatever) has decided the operation is not a double click, or when double clicked, but only once.  That is a series of clicks results in a notification every second click.  The user experience  is stuttered rotation.  The temporary workaround is to have users move the mouse slightly between clicks—It solves the problem, but is rather unfriendly.

The application does *no* double click event hooking.  Maybe there's a way to go further to disable potential double click processing?  Or maybe there is a lower-level way to capture the mouse button down?

Comment: As an aside drawing 3d objects using polygon calls through a dc will be very slow.  You'll get a lot better speed if you use the GetBitmapBits call and write your own triangle scan converter ... Or of course just use GL or DX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have it backwards - the first click gets through as a WM_LBUTTONDOWN, the second one gets turned into a double-click.

To prevent a window from generating WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK messages, remove the CS_DBLCLKS style from the window.

This is all explained in the [WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645606(VS.85).aspx) documentation.

**Edit:** I misspoke, CS_DBLCLKS is a class style, not a window style. I don't think you can remove it, you have to create a new window class that doesn't include it. It's provided by MFC - see this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a77269ff(VS.80).aspx.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct, OnLButtonDown <i>is</i> called on the first, third, etc. clicks, and the second, fourth, etc. clicks aren't delivered.

There is no CS_DBLCLKS anywhere; I stepped through CreateWindow() and it has the style bits set from my `CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow`:  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW  | WS_SYSMENU | WS_BORDER

Maybe one of those is "expanded" for me?

Comment: Forgive my delay in accepting your answer.  I didn't realize the checkmark outline was a control....

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an answer, this method worked for me:

```
    WORD dwStyle = GetClassLongPtr(handle, GCL_STYLE);
    dwStyle &= ~CS_DBLCLKS;
    SetClassLongPtr(handle, GCL_STYLE, dwStyle);
```

You can use these functions to edit a WNDCLASSEX style structure for an specific window removing the double click event and correcting the single click behavior.

[GetClassLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633581(v=vs.85).aspx)
[SetClassLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633589(v=vs.85).aspx)